# Evaluating the improper double integral $\int_{D} \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{1-a\cdot x-b\cdot y}}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

I'm given the following improper integral: $\int_{D} \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{1-a\cdot x-b\cdot y}}$ where $D$ is the open unit disk, assuming $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. I should decide whether it converges or not, and if it does, I should find the limit.

I've found that the integrand is well defined on $D$ (using Cauchy-Schwarz lemma) and by using this lemma I was able to upper-bound the integral by another and show that it converges. However, I cannot evaluate this integral, i.e. find its exact value. I'm quite sure I should integrate by substitution, but it is just not working... How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The disc is rotationally symmetric....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How can I use this fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint 1:**$\newcommand\dd{\mathrm d}\newcommand\INT{\int\limits}$

> Find a linear transformation (substitution) such that the integral becomes $$\int_D \frac{\dd u\,\dd v}{\sqrt{1-u}}.$$

**Hint 1 howto:**

> We have $$\INT_{x^2+y^2<1} \frac{\dd x\,\dd y}{\sqrt{1-ax-by}} = \INT_{u^2+v^2<1} \frac{\dd u\,\dd v}{\sqrt{1-u}}$$ with $u=ax+by$, $v=-bx+ay$.

**Hint 2:**

> Integrate first over $v$ and then over $u$.

**Hint 2 howto:**

> We continue $$\cdots = \INT_{-1}^1 \dd u \INT_{-\sqrt{1-u^2}}^{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\dd v\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}} = \INT_{-1}^1 \frac{2\sqrt{1-u^2}}{\sqrt{1-u}}\,\dd u.$$

**Hint 3:**

> This is an easy integral.

**Hint 3 howto:**

> We finish $$\cdots = \INT_{-1}^1 2\sqrt{1+u}\,\dd u = \frac{8\sqrt2}{3}.$$

Comment: it seems that you haven't used a^2+b^2=1.

Comment: @hashman it's hidden in **Hint 1 howto** if you do that step precisely.

Comment: explain please.

Comment: You have $$\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}.$$ Therefore the Jacobian is $$\begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}a & b\\-b & a\end{vmatrix} = a^2+b^2.$$ And also for the condition on $u^2+v^2$ you get $$u^2+v^2 = (ax+by)^2+(-bx+ay)^2 = \cdots = (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2).$$ So everything there holds only if $a^2+b^2=1$.

Comment: (Note that making properly the substitution in the integral when you know the transformation of coordinates is really basic stuff from Calculus. This should be a routine if you wanna solve problems like the one given here.)